# How to derive the start and end position of a column when the order (sequence number) and column length is known

Tags: oracle, window-functions

It’s a puzzle I’ve been trying to solve over the last two weeks. In Oracle there is a table called dba_tab_columns which contains a column CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH (indicates the column length) and along with the COLUMN_ID (indicates the Sequence number of the column created) it should be possible to derive the character start and end position for each column. I tried using a partition over approach but could not get correct results.

Comment: What do you mean "derive the character start and end position for each column"?  Are you talking about something like trying to figure out where within a particular block a particular column starts?  Assuming we're talking about `varchar2` columns, that's going to depend on the data not the maximum size of the column (and you'd want the size in bytes not characters).  If you're talking about something else, an example would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about something like trying to figure out where within a particular block a particular column starts? – yes exactly :)I wrote an apex application that extracts data from the Oracle database and creates a csv. The csv is imported into another application, but for legacy reasons this other app can only read data if I specify the start character position and character end position of a field…so imagine a regular csv but instead of specifying the field separator you’d have to calculate the start and end for each field…hence the reason for wanting to calculate the positions.

Comment: You're talking about producing a fixed width output file and producing a report for the consuming application of where the boundaries are?  That is hugely different than asking where in a block a particular column starts.  If you are trying to produce a fixed width file, will the character set of the file match the character set of the database?  Does the consuming application want positions specified in characters or bytes (and oh boy are there some corner cases when you get into Chinese and Japanese language data).

Comment: But it seems odd to want to generate this automatically rather than just saying "here are the 30 columns in the file, here's the length I'm padding/ truncating each character column to"